# PHP deleting wrong directory

Tags: php, function, web, filesystems, lamp

I am working on a prototype of an online storage with PHP and I got this problem. I call the `delete_file()` function from the client, the function checks if the item to be deleted is a file or a directory and deletes it accordingly. If the item is a directory then it will call another function that will delete all its' contents and the directory itself.

```
function delete_file (){
    global $directory;
    $rec_data = trim($_POST['selected']);
    $selected_items = explode(";", $rec_data);

    if (count($selected_items) < 1){
        echo "0";
    }
    else {
        foreach ($selected_items as $item){
            if (is_dir("{$directory}/{$item}")){
                recursiveRemoveDirectory("{$directory}/{$item}");
            }
            else {
                unlink("{$directory}/{$item}");
            }
        }
        echo "1";
    }
}

function recursiveRemoveDirectory($rm_directory){
    foreach(scandir($rm_directory) as $file){
        if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
            if(is_dir($file)) {
                recursiveRemoveDirectory($file);
            }
            else {
                unlink($file);
            }
        }
    }
    rmdir($rm_directory);
}
```

Problem: It works but, this also deletes the parent directory .e.g data > username > dir, if I want to delete dir, it will also delete username. I've tried with various other methods with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both answers, they did solve a problem I had with the code but it did not solve the issue I was having in which the parent directory was being deleted along with the selected items.

After looking and changing the code for some time I finally realized that the problem wasn't in the `recursiveDeleteDirectory()` function but in the `delete_file()` function itself.

The `$selected_items`variable gets a concatenated string of the names of the items to be selected, it trims any unnecessary whitespaces and makes an array from the string. The problem was that somehow $selected_items got an additional empty entry which meant that I was then executing `recursiveRemoveDirectory("{$directory}/");` instead of `recursiveRemoveDirectory("{$directory}/{$item}");`.

I solved all this by adding:

```
if (empty($item)){
    continue;
}
```

Here is how the code looks like:

```
function delete_file (){
    global $directory;
    $selected_items = explode(";", trim($_POST['selected']));

    if (count($selected_items) < 1){
        echo "0";
    }
    else {
        foreach ($selected_items as $item){
            if (empty($item)){
                continue;
            }
            if (is_dir("{$directory}/{$item}")){
                recursiveRemoveDirectory("{$directory}/{$item}");
            }
            else if (is_file("{$directory}/{$item}")){
                unlink("{$directory}/{$item}");
            }
        }
        echo "1";
    }

}

function recursiveRemoveDirectory($rm_directory){
    $files = file_explore();
    if(count($files) > 0){
        foreach($files as $file){
            if(is_dir("{$rm_directory}/{$file}")) {
                recursiveRemoveDirectory("{$rm_directory}/{$file}");
            }
            else if (is_file("{$rm_directory}/{$file}")) {
                unlink("{$rm_directory}/{$file}");
            }
        }
    }
    rmdir($rm_directory);
```

Now my problem, which isn't really a stack overflow problem is the naming conversions of php functions, I never used underscore on function names but recently that have changed and I feel that's a bad habit, if someone wants to comment about that, you are free to do so, I really want to know how things must be done in php.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
function recursiveRemoveDirectory($rm_directory){
    foreach(scandir($rm_directory) as $file){
        if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
            if(is_dir($file)) {                  <--- error starts here!
                recursiveRemoveDirectory($file);
            }
            else {
                unlink($file);                   <--- error ends here!
            }
        }
    }
    rmdir($rm_directory);
}
```

Replace the marked lines with

```
            if(is_dir("$rm_directory/$file")) {
                recursiveRemoveDirectory("$rm_directory/$file");
            else {
                unlink("$rm_directory/$file");
            }
```

You got that right in your `delete_file` function, but missed it in the recursive one.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still removes the parent directory.

Comment: It's a bit of guesswork because we don't know the initial input to delete_file. Put some echo statements in front of every call to `unlink`, `rmdir`, and `recursiveRemoveDirectory`, like `echo "unlinking $directory/$item in delete_file<br>\n"` or `echo "calling recursiveRemoveDirectory($rm_directory/$file) from recursiveRemoveDirectory<br>\n"`. This should help you find out what happens.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on my phone so as soon as I get to it I'll do it. Just so you know, the way everything works is that the client through ajax, calls the php file while passing the action to be performed (create folder, delete, etc) and relevant data like items to be deleted or name of the new folder to be created; in the php file I got functions for each action which then are called according to the action stated in $_POST through a case statement. Some action then send feedback depending on the result of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function recursiveRemoveDirectory($dir) {
    foreach(scandir($dir) as $file) {
        if ('.' === $file || '..' === $file) continue;
        if (is_dir("$dir/$file")) recursiveRemoveDirectory("$dir/$file");
        else unlink("$dir/$file");
    }
    rmdir($dir);
}
```

Comment: I also tied your suggestion but it still removes the parent directory for some reason.